# Dropwizard way of handling both GET and POST by single method

Tags: java, dropwizard

How to annotate a method in dropwizard so that a single method can handle my both post and GET

eg: Like

```
@POST
@GET
public void login() throws Exception{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408049/create-a-jax-rs-restful-service-that-accepts-both-post-and-get or doesn't use dropwizard jax-rs?

Comment: This answer specifically, but to do the same thing in a GET and POST sounds like a weird idea... http://stackoverflow.com/a/13408147/609176

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create a Jax-RS RESTful service that accepts both POST and GET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408049/create-a-jax-rs-restful-service-that-accepts-both-post-and-get)